# Double display of canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, canvas

The drawn lines appear not only in the Canvas-Element but also at the top of the page it is displayed again.

This happens when a touch event is been released.

Here you can find the source code and the result (PhoneGap and Jquery Mobile is used).

**Do anybody has an idea what’s the reason for this fault?**

[http://gomami.ch/bugs/screenshot.png http://gomami.ch/bugs/screenshot.png](http://gomami.ch/bugs/screenshot.png)

**JavaScript** (loaded in header after includes to jQuery/PhoneGap):

```
//*********************************************************
// Wait for Cordova to Load
//*********************************************************
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
  canvas("aufprallstelleA","test");
}

// function to setup a new canvas for drawing
function canvas(canvas, element){
    //define and resize canvas
    width = $(window).width();
    width = (width/100)*90;
    height = width/1.6901408;
    $("#content").width(width);
    $("#"+element).height(height);
    $("#"+element).width(width);
    var html = 'This is de Canvas field wehre you can draw<br><canvas id="'+
               canvas+'" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+
               '" style="border:black solid 1px;background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;background-image: url(\'images/allgemein/aufprallstelle.PNG\');"></canvas>';
    $("#"+element).html(html);      
    // setup canvas
    ctx=document.getElementById(canvas).getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;          
    // setup to trigger drawing on mouse or touch
    $("#"+canvas).on("touchstart", start);
    $("#"+canvas).on("touchmove", move);
}

function start(e){
    e = e.originalEvent;
    x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX-20;
    y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY-$(this).position().top;
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);
}

function move(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e = e.originalEvent;
    x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX-20;
    y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY-$(this).position().top;
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function clearcanvas(id) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(id);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="main">
  <div data-role="header" id="header">
    <div id="header_anzeige">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" id="content" >
    <div id="test" style="margin-top:265px;"></div><br>
    Hello, this is JQuery Mobile running in PhoneGap 2
  </div>   
</div> 
copyright
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there anyway you can get this into a jsFiddle, or provide a copy of what your HTML looks like once the page has finished loading and your javascript has built the canvas elements?

Comment: In my case, I used the code mentioned at http://www.pubnub.com/blog/multiuser-draw-html5-canvas-tutorial/ , I just adapted the mouse events to touch events. It works fine on computer, but on cordova apps, the drawing on canvas surface is reproduced on the main page with a shift to upper left...
Even if I draw a static drawing without passing throw touch events, this one is reproduced twice.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue by positionning the canvas in absolute instead of relative positionning as it's mentioned on https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5107

Answer (score 0):

`onDeviceReady` is probably called twice. Have you tried saving the canvas in a variable to avoid getting created twice? Note that the first one to get called is probably the faulty one, so the window size will most likely be wrong.

```
var theCanvas;
function onDeviceReady() {
    if(!theCanvas){
        canvas("aufprallstelleA","test");
    }
}

function canvas(canvas, element){
    //define and resize canvas
    width = $(window).width();

    [...]

    $("#"+canvas).on("touchmove", move);
    return $("#"+canvas);
}
```

EDIT: I did a bit of research, it does seem the problem is from the event being called twice. If you can confirm this we can look for a workaround.

Comment: If onDeviceReady is called twice, why when I put a alert("onDeviceReady"); into, it doesn't appear twice ?

Comment: I think the issue results from getContext that return pointers on canvas and both on the main screen... On phone gap ancient release there was no problem, whereas with the last version of Cordova, we can have this issue. But I don't find the way to solve it.

Comment: Could you call ˋcanvas()` from something like a button rather than from an event, and see If the problem still happens?

Answer (score 0):

try to surround the canvas with a div and apply the CSS overflow:hidden to this div.